# Clarification needed for offset in vloadn in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

[This page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/vloadn.html) says that `vloadn(size_t  offset, const gentype  *p)` "returns sizeof (gentypen) bytes of data read from address (p + (offset * n))". Does it imply that `short4 m = vload4(1920, p)` will read four 16-bit values starting from address `p+1920*4` or will it read one 16-bit value each from locations `p+1920*0`, `p+1920*1`, `p+1920*2` and `p+1920*3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p+1920*0, p+1920*1, p+1920*2 and p+1920*3
```

has a strided pattern but definition says it's a vector load and it doesn't say sparse vector so it has to be a

```
four 16-bit values starting from address p+1920*4
```

So it shouldn't be different than loading a struct with exception of alignment handling(maybe).

For strided copies, you can use

```
event_t async_work_group_strided_copy ( __local gentype *dst,
       const __global gentype *src,
       size_t num_gentypes,
       size_t src_stride,
       event_t event)
```